# Jenkins ERROR: No APKs in workspace matching app/build/outputs/apk/app-debug.apk

Tags: android, jenkins

When i was tried to generate apk using jenkins it gives me error like below.
Why is display no apk found.

```
Started by user anonymous
Building in workspace C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\ReadyBDev
 > C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
 > C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe config remote.origin.url https://github.com/ordextech/ReadyB.git # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from https://github.com/ordextech/ReadyB.git
 > C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe --version # timeout=10
using GIT_ASKPASS to set credentials 
 > C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe fetch --tags --progress https://github.com/ordextech/ReadyB.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
 > C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe rev-parse "refs/remotes/origin/master^{commit}" # timeout=10
 > C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe rev-parse "refs/remotes/origin/origin/master^{commit}" # timeout=10
Checking out Revision 55c44710113c9cfb541e86bbc9e42d4b626d1dc9 (refs/remotes/origin/master)
 > C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
 > C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe checkout -f 55c44710113c9cfb541e86bbc9e42d4b626d1dc9
Commit message: "Commit For Gradle Test"
 > C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe rev-list --no-walk 55c44710113c9cfb541e86bbc9e42d4b626d1dc9 # timeout=10
[ReadyBDjavascript:auth.signin($('#more-openid-options%20a.yahoo'));ev] $ cmd.exe /C "echo '"""resolving effective environment"""' && exit %%ERRORLEVEL%%"
ERROR: No APKs in workspace matching app/build/outputs/apk/app-debug.apk
[android-lint] Skipping publisher since build result is FAILURE
Archiving artifacts
Finished: FAILURE
```

Answer (score 1):

In the latest gradle versions, 4.x+ the output path for .apks has changed to also separate by release config, so you have to check where the .apk is in local build folder, it could be something like

```
app/build/outputs/apk/{flavor}/{debug|release}/app-{flavor}-{debug|release}.apk
```

And then adjust Jenkins config accordingly.

Comment: where can i configure this path ?